# Android Allow App to set Brightness permission using command line

Tags: android, brightness, system-setting

I tried different things but I'm not able to find a solution yet. My App wants the user to change the birghtness of the screen. A system dialog pops up, that this needs a special permission and I than have allow the App in System Settings to allow that.

Because I want to run instrumented tests on my device, I'm looking for a solution using the command line to grant that permission automativally.
All other permission are finde if I use:

```
   "adb -s " +device+ " install -g " +version
```

But this does not allow the brightness settings.
I tried:

```
    adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services screen_brightness
```

and

```
    adb shell appops set +app+ SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS allow
```

but this does not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
    adb shell appops set <app> WRITE_SETTINGS allow
```

that fixed it for me